# It is ok to delete found.000 folders range from ntfs partion?

Tags: partitioning, directory, ntfs

I am using `windows-Ubuntu` dual boot and have one `ntfs` partition which is used by both windows and `Ubuntu` But i don't understand why Ubuntu creates `found.000` `found.001` etc.folders?

I want to know all these folders are important ? or it is fine if we delete it ?.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These folders are created by the Windows Check Disk file system scans. They have nothing to do with Ubuntu. They may not have been visible on your Windows system, but they are visible on Ubuntu.

They may contain data rescued after a Windows system crash, so go through them in case you may miss something.